# Can't solve Time complexity of this exponential sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, exponential

```
A[n];
Sort(p,r) 
{
    if (A[p] > A[r]) then
        A[p]<->A[r];    //exchange
    if (p+1 >= r) then
        return;
    q <- (r-p+1) / 3;
    Sort(p, r-q);    // 2/3 of head
    Sort(p+q, r);    // 2/3 of tail
    Sort(p, r-q);    // again, 2/3 of head
 }
```

Hello, everybody.
This is the problem what I've learning in.
The algorithm works fine for sort.

`n   time
15  0.004
16  0.008
17  0.017
18  0.034
19  0.072
20  0.143
21  0.283
22  0.572
23  1.154
24  2.296
25  4.604
26  9.23
27  18.517`

above is how it take the times for n. 
(example : if n is 15, work like this. Sort(0,14) )

The Time complexity seems like 2^n  exponential. right?

But I don't how it is, because I thought it's T(n) = 3T((2/3)*n) + 1 = 3^n. 
It doesn't match with what I've got real time... 
Need for some help, please.

Comment: Are you sure that your bound on the recurrence is tight?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what to say...
I looked at the code you posted, and i think `T(n) = 3⋅T((2⋅n/3) + 1` is correct. **BUT** then  the master theorem says `T(n) = O(nlog3/2(3)) ≈ O(n2.7095)` or something like this. I simply not see the exponential time. So I write a test in PHP.

```
function WiredSort($p, $r, &$A)
{
    if($A[$p] > $A[$r])
    {
        $temp = $A[$p];
        $A[$p] = $A[$r];
        $A[$r] = $temp;
    }

    if($p + 1 >= $r)
        return;

    $q = round(($r-$p+1)/3);
    WiredSort($p, $r-$q, $A);
    WiredSort($p+$q, $r, $A);
    WiredSort($p, $r-$q, $A);
}
```

The call `WiredSort(0,n-1,$A)` runs
for `n=100` in 0.056003 sec,
for `n=110` in 0.056003 sec,
for `n=1000` in 0.390766 sec.

This also does not look exponential to me.

Where did you get your data?

Answer (score 0):

From time complexity using masters theorem on equation `T(n) = 3*T(2/3*n) + 1` we get `T(n) = O(n^(log(3/2)(3)) = O(n^(2.7))`  not `O(3^n)` so there is something terribly wrong in your implementation of the problem otherwise there is no way you can get exponential growth for that algorithm